# ¿Las sesiones en hosting compartido se pierden rápidamente?

Tags: php

Las sesiones en Godaddy en hosting compartido se pierden rápidamente, en menos de 30 minutos nuevamente toca ingresar los datos para iniciar sesión en la aplicación web.

Cualquier sesión que yo cree, por ejemplo:

```
session_start();
$variable = "prueba";
$_SESSION["verificar"] = $variable;
```

Está se elimina en el tiempo mencionado sin realizar ninguna acción, prácticamente después de un tiempo de inactividad en el sitio se elimina, no queda ningún tipo de registro de sesiones, dado a qué al hacer un:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Todo aparece en 0, null, no existe nada.

Este hosting no me permite modificar el archivo `php.ini` sin embargo he podido copiar el mismo archivo en mi dominio principal, he realizado algunos cambios pero otros no los deja Godaddy aparentemente ya que no se reflejan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo mencionó un cambio que no se ve reflejado, en `max_input_vars=30000` agregué 30 mil pero sigue siendo mil.

He agregado valores que he observado en la web, pero sin explicación a fondo, no se si puede afectar en rendimiento, seguridad o otros.

Por último he agregado lo siguiente a mis archivos php de mi aplicación:

```
 ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '172800');
 
//ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
//ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
 

ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime','172800');
$cookie_path = "/";
$cookie_timeout = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;



session_set_cookie_params($cookie_timeout, $cookie_path);
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_cache_expire(172800);
session_start();
//ini_set('session.save_path', '../../../PHPSecure/var/lib/php8/sessions/');
```

Han mencionado sobre esto como sesiones basura y, no entiendo muy bien el porque.

Existen sesiones como las de facebook, Hotmail, Gmail que nunca expiran.

Pero bueno, entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente exite riesgo de seguridad, rendimiento y, de que manera emplear para que las sessiones no se eliminen.

Comment: Eso busca es mitigar riesgos de seguridad que alguien vaya al historial, seleccione una URL de tu sitio y tenga una sesión iniciada sin que sepas si es el mismo usuario (porque no se ha autenticado). Los sitios que mencionas, validan muchas más variables para decidir si expiran la sesión en un dispositivo, es una mala comparación

Comment: @Alfabravo los sitios solo les mencioné por el gran tiempo que perduran sus sesiones, pero yo no logró que mis sesiones perduren y, hasta donde he investigado se debe porque es un hosting compartido dónde al parecer existe un crojobs que elimina estás sesiones durante tareas programadas.

Comment: @Otto puede ser posible que las sesiones de los sitios mencionados sea guardados en sesiones por base de datos, dichos datos puede que registre ip, navegador y su versión, puede que apliquen más parámetros para que sea más seguro, por ej: una cookie encriptada.

Comment: @KevinDelva Me parece interesante lo que me mencionas, cPanel usa este tipo de verificación, si se cambia de ip me obliga a iniciar sesión nuevamente.

Comment: @Otto podrías probar con los datos mencionados y guardar las sesiones por db, la otra opción menos segura es por un file con delimitador por comas (con lectura y escritura limitada) registrar la fecha de ingreso y una fecha expiración (opcional).
Para lo del navegador puede que este [enlace](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-browser.php) te sea útil

Comment: @KevinDelva ya hemos tratado algo de seguridad, pero como conservó las sesiones, porque como mencioné después de menos de 30 minutos las sessiones se pierden, se eliminan sin yo hacerlo.

Comment: Esa es la verdadera pregunta y, si no logras modificar tus parámetros de sesión para PHP, poco podrás hacer porque vas a perder esa info. No sé si te toque cargar cada vez algo que haga override de los parámetros en el ini

Comment: @Alfabravo la verdad no sé puede hacer mucho en el `ini` porque no todo lo que se hace ahí cambia, al menos supiera que parámetro se deben cambiar y porque? Que hace? Que resultados se obtiene? En estás configuraciones desconozco porque a más de desarrollar aplicaciones web con php jamás me tope con este problema y, como tengo dos años de contrato con ese hosting me toca buscar alguna solución.

Answer (score 5):

#### Edit 30-06-2021, Al grano

Existe la convención de incluir -cuando existe- un archivo de nombre `.user.ini` en el document_root de cada vhost (donde está el `index.php`, usualmente en una carpeta  `public`).

En ese archivo debes cambiar el setting `session.gc_maxlifetime`. El default son 1440 segundos o 24 minutos. Tú le estás poniendo 48 horas. En este momento no tiene efecto porque, como dice [la documentación de ese setting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime):

> If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data **then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data**. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.

O sea tus sesiones son válidas, pero el collector arrasa con todo cada 24 minutos. Debes indicar una ruta distinta para guardarlas con el setting `session.save_path`. Por ejemplo en la raíz de tu sitio, en una carpeta `.sessions` que habrás creado previamente. Es importante que el usuario `www-data` pueda crear archivos ahí dentro. Entonces sería:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = "172800"
session.save_path = "/var/www/otto/web/public/.sessions"
```

Pero si puedes escribir en un directorio superior al expuesto por el webserver sería mucho más seguro! (ej "/var/www/otto/.sessions" )

Y lo último, me ha pasado que, al mover el directorio de las sesiones en tiempo de ejecución, a veces la sesión figuraba inicializada y saltaba un warning que botaba el script. Si se diera ese caso, pienso que serviría añadir en el `.user.ini`:

```
session.autostart = false
```

Pero siempre puedes verificar en tiempo de ejecución [si la sesión está inicializada o no](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php):

```
  if(session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
     // todavía estás a tiempo de modificar tus settings
  }
```

#### Comentarios extensos y probablemente aburridos

En la versión original de esta respuesta intenté tocar todas las dudas planteadas en tu pregunta, las cuales entendí como

- Cómo o dónde poner un archivo que modifique el `php.ini`
- Por qué algunos de los `ini_set` que pongo no se toman en cuenta
- Cuál de todos estos settings sirve de algo
- Cómo lo hacen gmail o facebook para mantener al usuario autenticado durante meses
- Qué implicancias de seguridad hay
- Qué implicancias de performance hay

Luego en los comentarios entendí que lo medular es lo que puse al principio. Dejo esta parte como dato anexo

**Archivo ini custom**

Como dice al principio, la convención es buscar un archivo `.user.ini` en la raíz del vhost. Donde está el index.php, digamos. Generalmente, la carpeta `public`.

Si la configuración del proveedor de hosting compartido tiene definido el setting `user_ini.filename` con otro valor, por ejemplo, declarándolo en blanco, puedes restaurar la directiva usando

```
ini_set('user_ini.filename', '.user.ini');
```

Al principio de tu script principal.

Algunos valores de la configuración no se pueden modificar desde el `user_ini`. Específicamente:

> Only INI settings with the modes PHP_INI_PERDIR and PHP_INI_USER will be recognized in .user.ini-style INI files.

Puedes ver qué configuraciones son inamovibles revisando las que digan `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` [en la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

Todo lo anterior rige para PHP corriendo como FastCGI. Cuando corre con mod_php de Apache esto se hace en el `.htaccess` y no siempre se puede.
La sintaxis, además, es distinta. es distinta. Si el php.ini dijera, por ejemplo

```
display_startup_errors = on
display_errors = on
log_errors = off
```

El .htaccess diría

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag log_errors off
```

(pero no recuerdo si hay que declarar eso en un bloque especial)

**2.- Duración de la sesión**

La sesión se establece mediante la coincidencia de la cookie del usuario, usualmente llamada PHPSESSID, con aquella guardada en el servidor. Ésta puede estar en un archivo, en memcache, en Redis, y mediante drivers custom también en base de datos, DynamoDB y más.

PHP tiene un garbage collector que, al menos cuando se usan archivos, elimina las sesiones expiradas mediante una lotería entre los requests que vaya recibiendo. Si la probabilidad del GC es 1/1000, cada 1000 request uno será más lento porque justo a ese le tocó el premiado y gatilla el procedimiento.

Hay handlers de sesión (por ejemplo Redis) que tienen incorporado el manejo de llaves expirables y eso es mucho más eficiente. Además, las versiones más nuevas de PHP instalan un cron para correr el GC en segundo plano en vez de colgarse de un request.

Sin importar el handler que se elija, cuando éste expire las sesiones y eventualmente sean purgadas, la cookie que es la contraparte de la sesión en el browser deja de tener sentido, sin importar el tiempo de expiración asignado.

De la misma manera, si se asigna un tiempo de expiración para la Cookie que sea menor a la duración en el backend, aunque la sesión exista en el servidor la desaparición de la Cookie determina que quedas deslogueado.

Cuando la cookie no establece un tiempo de expiración se asume que durará lo que dure la sesión, o sea hasta que cierres el browser. Esto sin perder de vista que esa cookie puede perder validez del lado del browser por simple inactividad.

**3.- Caché de sesión**

El concepto de caché de sesión es engañoso. No se trata de cachear  las variables que has ido almacenando en la sesión ¿Cachear dónde y para qué, si en el momento que el request se valida como autenticado ya la tienes en memoria? El setting controla, en cambio, los headers relativos al caché con que te responde el backend cuando estás logueado.

A diferencia de la respuesta cuando no lo estás -que es homogénea para cualquier visitante- la respuesta de una petición autenticada probablemente contendrá en mayor o menor medida información que es específica para el usuario logueado. Si la respuesta del browser mostrando, por ejemplo, tu carrito de compras, viniera con caché `Public` , el browser lo almacenaría y probablemente lo seguiría mostrando aunque cierres sesión.

Lo anterior no significa que el caché asociado con la sesión sea el único contenido indeseable en el caché. Por ejemplo:

- Si el webserver tiene una capa de caché estilo Varnish
- Implementa una lógica en donde el primer request que pide un asset es el encargado de poblar el caché
- El resto de los visitantes recibirán lo que se ha guardado en caché hasta que expire

Entonces una configuración insegura podría permitir a un visitante malicioso poblar el caché con contenido igual de malicioso y atacar a los siguientes visitantes. [Owasp tiene una interesante sección sobre esta técnica conocida como Caché Poisoning](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Cache_Poisoning)

**4. ¿Cómo hacen otros sitios para mantener logueado a alguien?**

Técnicamente no hay límite para el tiempo que le das a  una cookie. Eso combinado con una duración muy larga del lado del servidor te mantendría logueado hasta que cierres sesión deliberadamente.

No necesitas ser amo y señor de los settings de la sesión para lograr este comportamiento. Por ejempo en Laravel el uso del checkbox "Remember Me" [es un mecanismo paralelo que guarda un token en la tabla de usuarios](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#remembering-users), y una cookie, distinta e independiente de la cookie de sesión, en tu browser, y sobre la cual se tiene seguridad que el garbage collector de PHP no la borrará sin preguntarle a nadie.

Para la comunicación a través de APIs ni siquiera se usan Cookies ni menos sesiones. Un API debiese ser stateless, y enviar su token en cada request. Es relativamente común que el token que recibes al autenticarte contra un API tenga un tiempo de expiración muy generoso y a veces eterno.

También existe la convención de computar un hash como función tipo

```
 hash = fn (login, dispositivo, aplicación)
```

Donde el dispositivo puede ser un móvil como un PC, y la aplicación puede ser desde Whatsapp al sitio de CNN que te ofrece enviarte notificaciones. Cuando te suscribes a las notificaciones (en el cuadrito de diálogo cuando es un browser, y tácitamente al instalar una app en el teléfono) el proveedor guarda ese hash y es su token para notificarte en segundo plano. En general esos tokens, también llamados notification_token y device_id, no expiran hasta que una de las partes no los invalide. Si bien esto no es propiamente un login permanente, el hecho que un sitio o una aplicación te siga "conociendo" como para notificarte indica que -al igual que en una sesión- sigue vigente un acuerdo entre las partes. En el caso de sitios que te obligan a autenticarte de nuevo si detectan un cambio de IP es simplemente que su algoritmo para computar la combinación única tiene en cuenta ese dato y su función es

```
  hash = fn(login, dispositivo, aplicación, IP)
```

Además estas funciones tienen siempre un factor aleatorio o al menos variable en el tiempo, cosa que yo no pueda computar maliciosamente el token de otra persona y spamearlo con notificaciones.

Finalmente, hace unos años existía un proyecto de cookies persistentes o derechamente duras de matar, que se replicaban en tu localstorage, sessionstorage, indexedDB y donde pudieran. Mientras quedara una, ésta poblaría el resto de "respaldos". Nunca más escuché de ellos y en verdad me sonaba invasivo.

Comment: Gracias por responder un gran aporte, con la primera parte de los `ini` podría solucionar el problema en que las sessiones se pierden en menos de 30 minutos? Y, los códigos de php en mi pregunta sirven para algo o no, seria bueno si las puedes explicar pero sino, no te preocupes :) pero por otra parte que configuraciones exactamente qué línea de código o que nombre de todo esos listados que se encuentra en el `ini` se deben cambiar para solucionar el problemas de sessiones.

Comment: Considero que esta pregunta aporta mucho, sin embargo creo que contiene mucha información y poco conocimiento, sugeriría resumir en concreto la posible solución a la pregunta

Comment: Me limité a responder el aspecto conceptual de las numerosas dudas que el OP planteó. Respecto a responder en concreto ¿Cuál de las 3 preguntas del final? Cualquiera sea la solución, en mi equipo local sería mucha prueba y error. Hacerlo con un tercero en un equipo remoto... inviable. Por eso la mejor alternativa era darle luz sobre lo que pasa internamente.

Comment: @FernandoTorres en realidad existen alternativas para solucionar este problema de las secciones y, en reubicar en otra carpeta esas sessiones, es decir guardar las sesiones en otra ruta para evitar que sea eliminada, el problema que la documentación no es clara, puedo cambiar la ruta pero no explican cómo consumir las sessiones de esa nueva ruta.

Comment: @ffflabs En realidad mi pregunta se basa a una sola pregunta, incluso los ejemplos expuestos son para el tema de sessiones, de tratar de solucionar dicho problema...Ya el tema de facebook, era para ver si alguna persona podría reforzar más que todo con el fin de que perduren las sessiones por mucho más tiempo. Sin embargo, lo que has publicado es una documentación interesante, muy útil pero no soluciona mi problema.

Comment: Pero también preguntaste sobre performance y seguridad. Según mi interpretación (y puedo estar mal) también sobre el `php.ini` en tu carpeta, las sesiones basura y el cómo lo hacían otros sitios. De todos modos voy a editar mi pregunta con una sugerencia